Spotlight search not showing up on display in focus
I have connected my macbook to an external display. My MacBook screen is currently on focus.
When I try to bring up the spotlight search with keyboard shortcut, it shows up on my external display. This is unintuitive as my MacBook is the one on focus.
Is there a way to bring up the spotlight search on the display in focus?

Is the Dock configured to hide automatically? The Spotlight search prompt appears on the display that showed the Dock last, so simply show the Dock on the screen you want the spotlight search prompt to appear and press Command-Space. By the way, the app switcher (Command-Tab) follows the same "logic", which is unexpected and, as you mention, quite unintuitive.
